# Change basemap depending on time of day?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

How would you change the basemap string in a leaflet / mapbox app depending on time of day?  I would like to create a basemap that shows current night/day division on world map for current user.

Comment: You may want to clarify exactly what you're looking for here. If you are trying to shade the map based on the day/night terminator line, there is a [plugin for that](http://joergdietrich.github.io/Leaflet.Terminator/). If you are trying to change the basemap depending on the time and user's location (showing one set of tiles for day and another for night), you may be able to use [SunCalc](https://github.com/mourner/suncalc), for example, to calculate when the sun is above the horizon and switch the tileLayers based on that.

Comment: nathansnider - I think you understood perfectly.  Great answer! That was exactly what I was hoping existed! Can't wait to apply this. thank you